# Mac Voiceover recognize select2 element as text

Tags: html, voiceover

I'm using jQuery select2 element on my website. However, when I tried to test Mac Voiceower I faced the issue that my select2 element recognized as a text by Voiceower.
Meanwhile regular select elements (as in code above) work and are recognized as **menu pop up, button.**

```
 <select>
   <option>test</option>
 </select>
```

Here is an example of select2 which recognizes incorrect:

```
<div class="select2-container select2 select2-container-active">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">   
        <span class="select2-chosen">Test</span>
    </a>
</div>
```